# Pressing G distorts my objects

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Whenever I press "G"  the selected vertices distort. The shape is retain with respect to the viewer but the vertices themselves are massively distorted. I'm assuming I've changed a setting without knowing. Can any help? This doesn't happen when I open a new file, but does happen in this .blend file everytime.

In the images below, I have selected the vertices I'd like to move, then moved them slightly. By rotating the camera you can see the actual damage caused.

[image: Vertices selected:]

[image: Pressed G and moved vertices slightly]

[image: Rotated view to observe damage]

Comment: I can't believe it, but after spending about 2 hours trying to figure this out, then posting this question, I just, by chance, found the cause. I had my snap setting set to "Snap to Face", rather than "Snap to Vertices".

Comment: Hey :). Glad you've found a solution! Please post your comment as a full answer, so it's easier to find.